# Separar resultado MySql em blocos no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select

Tenho uma tabela de imóveis divididos em várias categorias e quero listá-los na minha página em PHP. O detalhe é que desejo que, em uma região da página sejam listadas as casas, em outra os apartamentos e assim por diante.
Em outras situações eu fazia um select pra cada categoria, mas acho que isso não é bom em questão de performance.
Então, qual seria a melhor forma de fazê-lo?

Comment: Poderia postar seu código para a comunidade tentar lhe ajudar da melhor forma. Em termos de performance, existe tanto a forma do select, onde a medida que você selecione o que deseja o que será exibido se altera, e também através de checkbox que quando checkado altera o que será exibido atendendo a necessidade. Assim cada query teria uma condição e exibiria um resultado

Comment: Você pode separar trazendo o tipo do imóvel na `query`, e fazendo um `if` dentro do seu código. Coloque como esta seu código para te ajudarmos.

Comment: Ainda está em projeto, mas pretendo fazer uma <ul> listando os imóveis cuja categoria seja "casa" no banco de dados, em outra área da página, outra <ul> listando os imóveis cuja categoria seja "apartamento", e assim por diante.